# In CakePHP updates between associated models through triggers

Tags: cakephp

Lets assume following situation:

- A belongsTo B,C
- B hasMany A
- C hasMany A
- A has field quantity
- B has field total_quantity

Total quantities in B sums all individual quantities of all relevant individual records in A.

I have ModelC/edit where the user can add/delete/modify A.

I want to update B.total_quantity each time when records in A were appended, modified or deleted.

Basically, I have 3 possibilities to do the update:

1. manually in the ModelCController
2. in the ModelA.AfterSave
3. with triggers in the database

My first pick was solution 2, but I have found problems about it, so I need help.

In the ModelA.AfterSave I have only new, modified data. How could I know if A.quantity has been changed? There is no $this->old['ModelA'] or something like that. Even if I could know that information, I don't have access to ModelB, because there is no $this->data['ModelB']...

Anybody can help with this?

Comment: did you heard about counterCache feature for CakePHP models ? see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Comment: @JustinT. counterCache won't sum fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could study AggregateCache Behavior for CakePHP 2.x, here is a little snippet that should sit in your model B :

```
public $actsAs = array(
    'AggregateCache'=>array(
        array('field'=>'quantity','model'=>'A', 'sum'=>'total_quantity','recursive'=>-1),
    )
);
```

UPDATE : Full code now available @Github:
https://github.com/cwbit/cakephp-aggregate-cache

Vincent Lizzi put up the code here : http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/vincentm8/2010/08/23/aggregatecache-behavior

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm just now studying this great behaviour and it seems that it will fit my need.

Comment: @ZoranKalinić : you're welcome, if it works, be helpful to others and mark it as a correct answer